# Unable to resolve a class within the same package after integrating with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, compiler-errors

I have converted my project into maven. But the test classes are throwing errors saying that they can't resolve the classes. But the classes to be resolved are within the same package! Below is my project structure.

[image]

As shown in the image below it shows errors saying it can't resolve but when I hover over the error I do get the suggestion to import. When I click on the suggestion nothing happens.

[image]

Why is this happening? Please advice.

Comment: Does the project build on the command line? Have you performed a "cleanup" in Eclipse? (Project -> Clean …)

Comment: try right click> Maven> update project and then clean build,

Comment: This sounds silly but yes, cleaning the project did the trick! :) thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` on your project and after it refresh the project in eclipse.